# Removing items from list - Python

Tags: python, list

I am scraping data from local jail site. I am trying to remove all the elements from a list except for the charges. I want all the statutes, bond, etc, gone.

Here is what I have tried:

```
charges = [[], ['13A-12-214.1'], ["ECSO (ETOWAH COUNTY SHERIFF\\'S OFFICE)"], ['SALVIA MISD POSS'], [''], ['M'], ['$1000.00'], [], [], ['13A-10-41'], ["ECSO (ETOWAH COUNTY SHERIFF\\'S OFFICE)"], ['RESISTING ARREST'], [''], ['M'], ['$1000.00'], [], [], ['32.5A.88'], ["ECSO (ETOWAH COUNTY SHERIFF\\'S OFFICE)"], ['IMPROPER LANE USAGE'], [''], ['U'], ['$500.00'], [], [], [''], [''], ['DET FOR COMM CORR'], [''], ['U'], ['$0.00'], [], [], ['<tr>\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t        <td class="SearchHeader" colspan="2">']]

    for string in charges:
        if string == arrestedBy:
            charges.remove(string)
        elif string.isalpha() == False:
            charges.remove(string)
        elif len(string) < 2:
            charges.remove(string)

if charges[-1] == '<tr>\\r\\n\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t\\t        <td class="SearchHeader" colspan="2">':
    charges.remove(charges[-1])

charges = filter(None, charges)

charges = str(charges)
```

What I get instead is:

```
"ECSO (ETOWAH COUNTY SHERIFF\\S OFFICE)", $1000.00, "ECSO (ETOWAH COUNTY SHERIFF\\S OFFICE)", $1000.00, "ECSO (ETOWAH COUNTY SHERIFF\\S OFFICE)", $500.00, $0.00
```

What I want is:

"SALVIA MISD POSS, RESISTING ARREST, IMPROPER LANE USAGE, DET FOR COMM CORR"

Comment: don't remove elements from the list you are iterating over, how do you find the charges? If you are getting this from html you can probably filter long before you add the elements to the list

Comment: removing items from a list you're iterating is usually dangerous

Comment: From html using BeautifulSoup. I grab tags with certain attribute, strip them, and append them to the list. It grabs stuff I dont want too.

Answer (score 0):

If you can't limit what you are getting to charges when you are scraping, consider, rather than iterating over the list and deleting elements as you go (which is inadvisable), using python list comprehension.

For example, if you define some function `is_charge` that contains your logic for defining a charge and returns a boolean:

```
charges = [i for i in charges if is_charge(i)]
```

Comment: could you give me an example using my logic from above?

Comment: @PeterPope In your `for` loop, you're evaluating items in the list based on `string == arrestedBy`, `string.isalpha()`, et cetera - if you move these to a function that return `True` when the string matches the characteristics of a charge, you can keep those list items and drop the others.